# Why is the first item in my listview using a different selector on tablets?

Tags: android, listview, selector, tablet

This happens on a Google Nexus 10 and it's working properly on phones

---

So I need some reputation before I can post any images, however you can check it out here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Jyxj.png

The listview is working perfectly except when it comes to the first item. 
It gets drawn with different coloring (namely I'm noticing transparency being higher) and when using single choice mode it can get highlighted properly, but then keeps it's highlight when other items are pressed.

---

My list selector goes something like this:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:drawable="@android:color/transparent" android:state_window_focused="false"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/rounded_list_selector_disabled_holo_dark" android:state_enabled="false" android:state_focused="true" android:state_pressed="true"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/rounded_list_selector_disabled_holo_dark" android:state_enabled="false" android:state_focused="true"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/list_selector_background_transition_holo_dark" android:state_focused="true" android:state_pressed="true"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/list_selector_background_transition_holo_dark" android:state_focused="false" android:state_pressed="true"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/rounded_list_focused_holo" android:state_focused="true"/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem with a Galaxy Note 10.1 and I thought it would be some hardware related issue. But indeed I was using the wrong procedure of ListView.

Unfortunately I don't know which ("wrong") method I was calling, but the one you're looking for is:

```
ListView.setItemChecked(int position, boolean checked)
```

In SingleChoiceMode it might be necessary to uncheck the previously checked item.

Let me know whether it works.

Edit 2: Removed my previous edit (was useless)

Comment: This partly solved my problem. Now the item doesn't keep it's highlight, however the coloring of the item is still the same.

Comment: I wish I could tell you that it works, but it doesnt :( Nothing really changes with that line.

It seems that somehow its using a different drawable source for the 1st item, the corners are rounded but not as rounded as they should be. Im starting to suspect that its a bug.. Any other ideas?

Comment: Are those drawables the default android-holos? Or did you create or modify them and put them in your project's own drawable-xxxx folders? And it's working perfectly on a phone?

Comment: Theyre my own ones, and yes they work perfectly on the phone and Im using the same ones for the tablet.

Comment: Tablets and (also phones) use the drawable-xxxx folder that suits their screen density. If you want to use the same graphics / drawables regardless of the density, you'll have to put them into a folder called 'drawable' or 'drawable-nodpi'. An hdpi-device won't use the drawables from mdpi. It will use the ones from hdpi or if none given the default Android drawables. Otherwise you could create drawables for every density and put them into the respective folder.

Comment: Yes, thats exactly what Im doing. I have the selector in the drawable folder and specific graphics for the different sizes and versions in drawable-v11 etc etc. Im gonna accept your answer since it helped me with the item getting checked, however the other thing seems to be a mystery.

Comment: Thanks for accepting :) So you got drawables for each android version and screen density. Hmm, have you checked the graphics? Maybe they're indeed different (another transparency setting)? (Sometimes it can get really confusing with all those different dpi-drawables for a simple selector. Maybe you forgot to replace an old version with the new one?)

Comment: Theyre all the same, Ive checked :( And if they were different then all list items would be different, now its just the first one. Which makes it even more confusing.

Comment: Would you mind uploading some screenshots of that behaviour? Also, it would be nice, if you post the code, where the highlighting (setItemChecked... etc.) takes place. (Maybe you unintentionally manipulated the transparency setting of the selector somewhere in the code.)

Comment: I dont know if youve missed it but Ive posted a picture of the behaviour up there! Heres the link anyways: http://i.imgur.com/2tG6b0h.png and as I wrote earlier no items are selected, just pressed, so Im not really using any code for that.